# Pattern matching in shell - not full exact pattern

Tags: shell

How to do pattern match in shell

```
    if ( $var ~= /abc/)
```

As we do like the above command in perl.

Comment: You should explain what you want rather than providing code in a language the people who could answer might not know. Also, there's at least half a dozen commonly shells, so you should specify which one you're talking about! This is a very poor question. Please fix it up.

Answer (score 2):

Using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
if [[ $var =~ regex ]]; then ...; fi
```

or

```
if [[ $var == *string* ]]; then ...; fi
```

or if not using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) :

```
if echo "$var" | grep &>/dev/null regex; then ...; fi
```

See
http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/ccmd/conditional_expression
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Patterns